# MongoDB Compass timeouts

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I'm using MongoDB Compass to perform an aggregation on a reasonably large dataset (~2,000,000 documents, 300MB) through an SSH tunnel.

It connects fine and I can query but stages in my pipeline appear to timeout `operation exceeded time limit`.

[image]

I know via the command line you can set the max time in milliseconds for a query using [maxTimeMs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/maxTimeMS/) `$maxTimeMS` but is it possible to apply this in MongoDB Compass?

I have also looked for connection timeout settings and can't find anything related to that in the GUI.

Comment: I've just managed to fix the above by moving the $match to happen first but this question still applies

Comment: having the same issue with aggregate. Is it possible to change timeout setting?

Comment: I've found in `/usr/share/mongodb-compass-community-beta/resources/app.asar` that there is a constant `const DEFAULT_MAX_TIME_MS = 10000;`. I have tried to unpack the `asar` file and succeed, and then found two files where the constant appears. But I found no way to rebuild the `app.asar` file.

Comment: I've open a ticket on mongoDB JIRA : https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/COMPASS-3753

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Compass 1.19-beta we added an option to set maxTimeMS in the aggregation pipeline builder and in the query bar.

[image: Compass 1.19 agg builder options]

Comment: Looks a little different in the non-beta version 1.19.12 (1.19.12) which you can find by clicking options to the right of the filter search bar and `MAXTIMEMS` will be there.

Comment: Does this timeout apply to the "Explain Plan" tab? It doesn't appear to. Is there a way to extend that timeout?

Comment: For Explain plan (and similarly, for Schema and regular queries in the Documents tab), you have a maxTimeMS field in the query bar. Click on Options to expand it and see all the options.

Answer (score 12):

To anyone came here to fix this problem on other tabs.

in `filter search` click on `options` when it expands, change `MAXTIMEMS` to any second you want, the value must be in `millisecond`.

then you can use `FIND`, `ANALYZE` or `EXPLAIN` depends on the tab you chose.

[image: mongodb compass]

Comment: Thanks a million. I was looking for this all over the town.